# How do I increase the speed of RawTurtle?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

I'm currently using an embedded turtle canvas in a tkinter window. While it's intuitive that all I need to do is set my turtle to turtle.RawTurtle(canvas), there are some functions that just don't work, and I can't figure out why.

```
t.clear();t.pu();t.speed(0);t.ht();t.tracer(0)
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'RawTurtle' object has no attribute 'tracer'
```

Despite this, many other functions work, such as clear, penup, speed, and hideturtle.

Is there any way of disabling screen updates until the drawing is finished, then manually updating the canvas, with RawTurtle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tracer()` method is a method of the turtle's screen, not the turtle itself.  To get access to it, when embedded under a tkinter window, wrap the canvas in a turtle screen:

```
screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas)

t = turtle.RawTurtle(screen)
```

which should give you access to the various screen methods.  Then you should be able to use `screen.tracer(0)` to turn off drawing updates and `screen.update()` to show the finished drawing.  A more complete example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = turtle.ScrolledCanvas(root)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas)

t = turtle.RawTurtle(screen)
t.hideturtle()
# t.speed('fastest')

screen.tracer(0)

t.penup()
t.sety(-100)
t.pendown()
t.circle(100)

screen.update()
screen.mainloop()
```